# How can I get more catpower in Iron Will mode?

Tags: kittens-game

I played through the kittens game in normal mode, got to 150 or so kittens, and got most (all?) of the religious and tech upgrades except the necrocorn stuff, so I decided to reset and try Iron Will mode.  I played through Iron Will until the space program but found I couldn't complete the moon mission because I maxed out somewhere around 1200 catpower and it required 5000.

I decided maybe I needed more zebras (plus I wanted the zebra chief achievement) so I reset and started another IW game.  However I'm not ever getting more than 1 zebra (despite all the info I've found online about karma zebras carrying over through resets).  I've tried resetting additional IW games after acquiring a zebra but still never more than 1 shows up.

Will the extra zebras increase my catpower as I suspected?  If so, how do I get more to show up?  If not, how can I get the required 5000 catpower for a moon mission?  I had all the catpower related upgrades in my first IW game but had not been able to get any more max catpower.

Comment: There was a bug, which has since been patched. Your karmic zebras should work correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

The first option that comes to my mind is religion. If you worship the Order of the Sun enough, the Templars ability will let temples increase your catpower limit. Get far enough into the Order of the Sun and you'll unlock Transcendence which will let you purchase that ability multiple times, though at a constant scaling of 2.5x the previous cost.